# Add a checkbox to contact form to subscribe to Campaign Monitor mailing list

Tags: wordpress, campaign-monitor

I have a contact form in a Wordpress site which I'd like to add a checkbox too - to automatically if checked, add the form filler's email address to a mailing list I have on Campaign Monitor....

Can anyone advise on how to do this? I have seen the notes here - http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=117 but not sure how to implement them in practice! - I will need the form submit button to first add the email address to the mailign list and then complete the existing form success function...

The form is built with Contact Form 7 version 3.9.1

Any ideas chaps?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using MailOptin plugin which act as a bridge between [contact form 7 and campaign monitor](https://mailoptin.io/article/contact-form-7-mailchimp-aweber-more/).

The screenshot below is for Mailchimp but you should get the idea on how it works

[image: cf7 to mailchimp]